# F-strings in Python 3.6.1: If f-strings do not use local or global variables, then how do f-strings function? I'm confused

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, local-variables, f-string

I read in the Python 3.6.1 documentation that f-strings do not use local or global variables. While I do understand the reasoning that f-strings do not need to access the excess information provided in local or global variables, I do not understand how the f-string functions when it reads a local or global variable.

Here is an example provided by the documentation:

```
import datetime
name = 'Fred'
age = 50
anniversary = datetime.date(1991, 10, 12)

f'My name is {name}, my age next year is {age+1}, my anniversary is {anniversary:%A, %B %d, %Y}.'

f'He said his name is {name!r}.'
```

Which produce the following output:

```
'My name is Fred, my age next year is 51, my anniversary is Saturday, October 12, 1991.'
"He said his name is 'Fred'."
```

Aren't "name", "age", and "anniversary" global variables in the code? If they are, didn't the f-string use these global variables?

Here is a link to the documentation I took the example from.

[Python 3.6.1 documentation: f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#no-use-of-globals-or-locals)

Thanks you for your patience and kind assistance.

Comment: They are indeed variables in your code, and when included inside the replacement fields (ie. the ones between '{}') they are considered as expressions and evaluated at run time. See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings